# how to fix org.osgi.framework.BundleException

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, sdn, onos

I'm running ONOS and when I want to add my module to its core I get this exception.
that was OK before but when I changed my OS, I get this error.

I've tried lots of ways but none of them fits my problem.
I also have no POM file to add dependency.
any other suggestions would be appreciated

```
ERROR: Bundle sdn.FANA.optical.optical [178] Error starting mvn:sdn.FANA.optical/optical/1.0 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle sdn.FANA.optical.optical [178]: Unable to resolve 178.0: missing requirement [178.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.karaf.shell.api.action)(version>=4.2.0)(!(version>=5.0.0))))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle sdn.FANA.optical.optical [178]: Unable to resolve 178.0: missing requirement [178.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.karaf.shell.api.action)(version>=4.2.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3974)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2037)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1291)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 2):

This error message says that your bundle depends on the package `org.apache.karaf.shell.api.action`, version range `[4.2.0, 5.0.0)`.

Whenever a bundle has an import, it must be matched by a corresponding export from another bundle. So you need to install the bundle that exports the package `org.apache.karaf.shell.api.action`, with version at least 4.2.0 and less than 5.0.0.

Comment: can you tell me a link that I can know how to install a bundle?
Generally how does bundles work.

Comment: Well, how did you install the bundle `sdn.FANA.optical.optical`? Do the same thing.